# RAID 1 Rebuild - Old OS and new OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, raid1

My task is to do a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard re-installation on a DELL Server. All data will be migrated to the new Installation. The server has only two HDD's in RAID 1.

To have a backup solution, I will remove one of the Disks and install the new OS on one of the disks only. If everything goes smoothly I will install the spear HDD and rebuild the array.

So, how the RAID 1 will be rebuild in this case? Is there a danger of writing the old OS data on top of the new one? How do I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Making a **real backup**, that you have actually tested is usually a better option then messing around with breaking your RAID1.  It sure seems like you need a **backup system** in place instead of trying to treat your RAID as a backup.

Comment: I should have mentioned it, but backups are available and I will also make a final image of the HDD's for that matter. The main reason for this, is in case I need something (configs etc) from the Old OS. Thought, I can see your point of messing around with the RAID.

Comment: I really don't understand this approach. Back up the old server. Build the new server. Back up the new server. Restore data as needed.